# How to convert a nested dict to a dataframe, without converting the inner keys to columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've a nested dict that looks like this:

```
{'1995-01-03': {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)},
 '1995-01-04': {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)},
 '1995-01-05': {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)},
 '1995-01-06': {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)},
 '1995-01-09': {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)},
 '1995-01-10': {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)},
 '1995-01-11': {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)},
 '1995-01-12': {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)},
 '1995-01-13': {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}}
```

but I do not want the nested dictionary to be converted to rows.

I would like it to be to like this:

```
        index                                            values
0  1995-01-03  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
1  1995-01-04  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
2  1995-01-05  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
3  1995-01-06  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
4  1995-01-09  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
5  1995-01-10  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
6  1995-01-11  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
7  1995-01-12  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
8  1995-01-13  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `pd.Series`.

```py
dfn = pd.Series(data, name='values').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is stored in a variable named `v`, this does the trick:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(v.items(), columns=['index', 'values'])
        index                                            values
0  1995-01-03  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
1  1995-01-04  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
2  1995-01-05  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
3  1995-01-06  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
4  1995-01-09  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
5  1995-01-10  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
6  1995-01-11  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
7  1995-01-12  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
8  1995-01-13  {91: (0, 1), 74: (1, 2), 78: (1, 3), 85: (1, 4)}
```